Updating IIS URL rewrite configuration causing 500 Internal Server error?
Occasionally in the web browser or a client application I am seeing a 500 Internal Server Error that appears to come from IIS itself reading its web.config file. The server I saw this happen on is running Windows Server 2019 with IIS 10.0.17763.1.
As far as I can tell, we never modify the config file directly, only using Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager with some services that run as their own ASP.NET process.  Looking at that assembly it appears to call the native IAppHostWritableAdminManager::CommitChanges.
Can ServerManager cause this, or would it be some other rogue process on the server locking the file occasionally?
If it does cause it, is there any way other to update an IIS rewrite rule without triggering downtime? Maybe write a new web.config file without "locking" the existing one then swap the active config?
using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
{
    Configuration config = serverManager.GetWebConfiguration("Softdial");
    ConfigurationSection rulesSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/rewrite/rules");
    ConfigurationElementCollection rulesCollection = rulesSection.GetCollection();
    ConfigurationElement ruleElement = rulesCollection.CreateElement("rule");
    ruleElement["name"] = "My Rule";
    ruleElement["stopProcessing"] = "true";

    ConfigurationElement matchElement = ruleElement.GetChildElement("match");
    matchElement["url"] = @"example/(.*)";

    ConfigurationElement actionElement = ruleElement.GetChildElement("action");
    actionElement["type"] = @"Rewrite";
    actionElement["url"] = "http://localhost:8999/{R:1}";
    actionElement["logRewrittenUrl"] = "true";

    rulesCollection.Add(ruleElement);

    serverManager.CommitChanges();
}

Server Error in '/' Application.
Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: An error occurred loading a configuration file: The process cannot access the file 'C:\MyWebSite\web.config' because it is being used by another process.

Source Error:


[No relevant source lines]

Source File: C:\MyWebSite\web.config    Line: 0


Click here to show additional error information:

Exception Details: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\MyWebSite\web.config' because it is being used by another process.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\MyWebSite\web.config' because it is being used by another process.]
   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +935
   System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) +1242
   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share) +126
   System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.StaticOpenStreamForRead(String streamName) +102
   System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigHost.OpenStreamForRead(String streamName, Boolean assertPermissions) +149
   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.InitConfigFromFile() +470

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.4718.0


You can also try to use failed request tracking to view detailed error information.

@samwu The full error is in the question. What further information would you expect?

Log file for failed request tracing.

Could it be that CommitChanges opens the file for writing but doesn't allow subsequent reads? Without peeking into its source, you can assume it does so, considering the exception message.
When the web.config is locked for reads and a request comes, IIS seems to just throw the exception.

If it does cause it, is there any way other to update an IIS rewrite rule without triggering downtime?

Yes there is. There are a couple of options that evolve from the idea of Blue-green deployment.
Option 1. Have at least two servers behind a reverse proxy (works with more than two, too). Disable the first so that the traffic goes to the second. Update the first. Switch traffic to the first. Update the second. Enable traffic to both.
A disadvantage of this is that you need to scale down the traffic for a short period of time.
Option 2. (doesn't require multiple servers) Have two identical physical copies of your app in two separate folders. Configure IIS to use the first. Update the second. Switch IIS configuration to use second. Update the first.
An advantage of this is that switching a path of application files in IIS web site is instant and shouldn't cause anything than just a restart of your app.
Depending on how you deploy, one of the two options could fit you better.

"Switch IIS configuration to use second." how would we do that to avoid the downtime? That is effectively why we are trying to update the URL rewrite in the first place here, because a new HTTP process/listener has started on a different port so needs a proxy/rewrite added/updated.

Trying to trace the client code, it seems to end up in a native IAppHostWritableAdminManager::CommitChanges

As far as I remember, updating website settings in IIS doesn't cause the downtime, the app just restarts but there are no locked files. If this is false, consider option 2 as invalid, however, if I were you I'd still give it a chance. Anyway, the option 1 still holds.

Far as I can tell from further testing, its the web.config file being locked (to make the changes) if IIS sees the locked file it just quits the request (rather than say using a previous cached config). It's only going to be locked for a couple ms I guess but if you have high load there will be requests in that window :(

Yes. And updating site configuration in iis is not the same as updating the web.config. You have problems when updating web.config and you could try one of the two options from my answer.

Option 1, if the separate server is IIS we still have the same problem to update the reverse proxy rule? Potentially just considering at that point using NGINX rather than IIS at all, as it seems to be more commonly used for reverse proxy than the IIS URL Rewrite module.

Option 2. How would you envision to "Switch IIS configuration to use second" without changing the reverse proxy rule to point to the new process?

(also found changing the global rewrite rules in applicationHost.config seemed to have similar problems to doing it at the site level in web.config)

(option 1) you update web.config on a first server while its the second that handles the traffic. Because you update on a server that doesn't handle any traffic, updating the web.config doesn't cause 500.

(option 2) this option is about folders. If IIS is configured to have the web site in a folder, you can safely update any other folder. Then you update web site path in IIS, the update doesn't lock any files (as you only update the web site physical location in your file system).

From what I understand what your concerns about my suggestions are, either you never tried the Blue-Green deployment or I miss something critical in your problem statement.

So say we have a service running on http://foo:5000, we start a new instance on http://bar:5005. The problem is IIS is the https://example.com/myservice/ "entry point", so we need to update the IIS rewrite rule to direct traffic from the old location to the new location. And this update seems to cause the 500's under load. So option 1 just moves the problem, how do we move traffic between the "first and second server" without a 3rd server that we update a rewrite on (unless went to NGINX or something, and that could just do the https://example.com/myservice/ ->  http://foo:5000 proxy anyway).

I'll test with option 2 some more maybe we did it wrong. IIS seems to store the "web site path" in applicationHost.config under configuration/system.applicationHost/sites/site/application/virtualDirectory. Trying to update under load test I saw a few 500's and even one crash of a w3wp.exe. So maybe IIS just isn't designed to handle this :(

Option 1 using the ARR as a rev proxy is something we do for years. A proper rev proxy (like ARR) in contrast with bare IIS, finishes processed requests before it switches the config. There is no downtime.

ARR supports routing on top of web apps. Could be that just having it in front would solve your issues completely (ARR has other features as well).
